# Function's argument as False and True

Tags: python, numpy

I want to understand the following piece of code. In object oriented part one of the argument is `one_hot= one_hot`. But if I call function `extract_labels` with `one_hot=one_hot` it does not work. I am bound to use `True` and `False` statements. Can someone please guide me why is it so? And what these `True` and `False` indicate. I printed result when I use `one=True` while calling `extract_label` function it prints one hot vectors.

```
#Functions
def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes=2):

    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = numpy.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = numpy.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot
def extract_labels(labels, one_hot=False):
    if one_hot :
        return dense_to_one_hot(labels)
    return labels

#Object oriented part
def read_data_sets(all_width_dir,width_dir, one_hot=False):
    class DataSets(object):
    pass
    data_sets = DataSets()
    train_labels = extract_labels(TRAIN_LABELS, one_hot=one_hot)
    test_labels = extract_labels(TEST_LABELS, one_hot=one_hot)

return data_sets

train_label = np.load("./Input/1.5/train_label.npy")
labels = extract_labels(train_label, one_hot=one_hot)
print(labels)
```

Comment: what d you mean it does not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: what do you expect `one_hot` to be set as when you call the function like that? What you're telling it is "use the value of variable `one_hot` as the value for the function parameter `one_hot`" but there is no such variable when you call it

Comment: Yes I am getting error name one_hot is not defined if I put one_hot=one_hot while calling function as in second last line of above code

Comment: I have to set some value(true or False) because one of the argument is one_hot. I am wondering why inside OOP it is one_hot=one_hot. Why it is not True or False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user *calls* the function `read_data_sets()` defined as

```
def read_data_sets(all_width_dir,width_dir, one_hot=False):
```

it may but *need not* provide the value for the last parameter, because it is the *keyed parameter* - with the key `one_hot` and the default value `False`. In both cases, the parameter `one_hot` **will have a value** - provided, or default.

Now let examine the last two lines in the full definition of that function:

```
def read_data_sets(all_width_dir,width_dir, one_hot=False):
    class DataSets(object):
    pass
    data_sets = DataSets()
    train_labels = extract_labels(TRAIN_LABELS, one_hot=one_hot)
    test_labels = extract_labels(TEST_LABELS, one_hot=one_hot)
```

Both of them call the `extract_labels()` function, and both of them provide the value for the keyed parameter with the *key name* `one_hot`. The provided value is the content of the *variable* `one_hot` - it is the parameter of the (currently defined) function `read_data_sets()`, and as I mentioned in the start, it **has some value** - *provided by caller*, or *the default* one(`False`).

---

Note:
It is a little confusing that in the `one_hot=one_hot` parameter there are the same name for the *key* - on the left hand - and the *provided value* on the right hand.)

---

But after function definitions, i. e. on the module level, there is no variable with the name `one_hot` - this name were *local* to function definitions.

So you have in function call

```
labels = extract_labels(train_label, one_hot=one_hot)
```

provide the value for the keyed parameter either directly (e. g. `one_hot=True`), either indirectly by variable, to which you assign a value in advance (e. g. `xyz = True` and then in the function call use `one_hot=xyz`), or accept the *default value* (`False`) by *totally omitting* the keyed parameter:

```
labels = extract_labels(train_label)
```

Comment: From this I can infer that if I don't assign any value to the one_hot it will pick default value that is False. But in above code we haven't defined any one hot variable so when we put one_hot=one hot why it works.

Comment: Read carefully my answer. In the statements of the **definition** of the function `read_data_sets()` the `one_hot` variable (parameter) *has* some value, but it is *local* - after the function definition it simply *don't exist*.

Comment: You *can* assign *any* value to the one_hot parameter - it will have *precedence over the default value*.  The default value is used only if you don't assign a value.

Answer (score 2):

Function extract_labels has 2 arguments:

- labels - required, has no default value
- one_hot - optional, which has default value False

To call extract_lablels like one_hot=one_hot you need to specify one_hot variable before